# Netbeans does not react on changes in C++ project options

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile

I'm trying to use Netbeans 8.2 to develop small c++14 project. When I created project, Netbeans creates makefile. Next, I try to change standard for c++14:

[image: Project options]

First, I change C++ Standard. No reaction. Next I add additional options explicitly. No reaction, build commands are like this:

```
g++ -g   -c   -o GNU-amd64-Linux/MultiplePandigital.o MultiplePandigital.cpp
```

There is no -std option, and compilation fails. How to force Netbeans to generate makefile that builds project with necessary options?

Comment: Now I switch in QtCreator. Seems all works fine.

Comment: I'd recommend writing `makefile` by hand, rather than relying on IDE to generate one. That way you'll have more control on how is actually the project is built and you will be able to make builds even without IDE, which is useful for Continuous Integration.

Comment: Absolutely agree, but it is small project for testing complexity of some math algorithms. It is not large solution, I want only write code and run it.

Comment: Have a look at my template library for non-recursive makefiles: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBuildApplication.md writing makefile with it is very simple and fast, basically you only need to set the list of sources to a variable and desired compilation flags to another one, and that's it, all the needed rules for building will be generated by the library.